# How to set Pre + Post Build Event to remove Read-Only attribute from ALL files/folders?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm running into Unauthorized issues with our new TFS build templates on the build machine when TFS attempts to build our solution - multi-proc is causing issues and after days of researching/troubleshooting, I'd like to try and set a pre and post build event to mark all files/folders as NOT read-only. I have this:

```
attrib -r "$(ProjectDir)*.*"
```

But I'm not sure that this will work as expected (all folders/files/subfolders etc).

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing but I'm not having any luck. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot **call**, this should work:

> `call attrib -r "$(ProjectDir)*.*" /s`